# ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatToolbar -> ElementRef]

Tags: javascript, angular

I got a error when using @angular/material with my first day.
The versions like this:

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.2.0",
...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.2.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
```

I import modules in app.module.ts:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
// the third modules
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import 'hammerjs';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { BaseDataComponent } from './base-data/base-data.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    BaseDataComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatToolbarModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then I use the mat-toolbar in html, but when I run it in browser, I got a error in console:
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Pm0T.png)
I googing a lot but still have the problem, could anyone help me? plz!

Comment: Did you installed this package via npm?

Comment: I success to solve this ! Cause I get lots of warnings when ng serve, and  solve it with this: https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/issues/926. Then done!

Comment: which error do you get? plz show us the full error so we can help

Comment: I later found the reason was I got warnings when I ran "ng serve", and I solved it with the issues github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/issues/926. thx a lot!

Comment: @kamilNaja yes I executed npm install, but having warnings, I think that's the reason! And I've solved it now ^^